# Ink blue molds/fungi/dermatophytes

Tags: anatomy, mycology, color

Which of the above has naturally ink blue hyphae? Are there any that make both Ochratoxin A and fumononis toxin and have hyphae that color?

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: I have chased down all research articles thatI can find. I know know there are about 10 Aspergillus Niger subspecies, some used in industry that have this ability. I can’t find references to their specific names and no descriptions or images. Thus, I don’t know what they are named or what they look like. There also may be a remote chance that there are dermatophytes that do the same. I was hoping someone familiar with the specialized nature of these organisms might remember some obscure facts they might have stumbled on or someone who is researching these for possible industry use might know.